# Windows 10 activation

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

Now that I've upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, what happens if my motherboard fails? Can I use my Windows 8.1 Pro media to install 8.1 to a new PC and go through the Windows 10 upgrade activation again (on a new system)?

From my understanding, Windows 10 is now tied to my hardware (motherboard). I did not originally purchase an OEM product. I originally purchased a retail copy of Windows 7 Home. When Microsoft offered the cheap upgrade to Windows 8 Pro for $25, I purchased this.

Comment: Your initial purchase was also tied to that motherboard, or at the whim & final decision of Microsoft if you ring them up & plead, to your next motherboard...

Comment: @xxl3ww The license is tied to your motherboard, however, I've had two situations where I've had to replace a motherboard (once with Vista and once with Windows 7) and Microsoft never questioned anything when I called them on the phone to reactivate. I think they assume if you are willing to call them up, you clearly aren't trying to be a weasel and get the software for free. Your mileage may vary, but that's been my experience.

Comment: With windows 10 upgrade it will deactivate the W8 key after 30 days. If it is OEM custom recovery media (HP, Acer, ect) you may be able to reinstall w8 after that period since that type of installation is pre activated upon install.. You are best to make a hard drive image of the activated W8 install using 3rd party software, then use that image to restore W8 to the hard drive at a later date if needed, that way it will be pre activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows 10 Hardware ID is not tied specifically to the motherboard, but to the entire device.  Microsoft understands that failures on hardware can happen from time to time.  So long as the upgrade was performed properly on the original hardware, there is a percentage of hardware that can be replaced without effecting the Windows 10 activation. Hardware ID specification can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552325(v=vs.85).aspx