# Does Windows 10 OEM License will work if I replace the HDD and install the windows from Microsoft ISO

Tags: windows-10, ssd, license, oem

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 310 which sometimes going 100% Hard disk usage. I research on the internet and found out removing "system interface" software make work fine. I did it and performance of system increase. I remove every bloatware Lenovo add into my PC by default.

Today I got wasted 30 minutes. System hangs too much. If I update my system to SSD and install the Same windows 10 Home Edition which I have by download Windows 10 Recovery Media (Windows 10 Recovery tools) it's give me the ISO of my system.

Does my OEM licene will work. My system is 1TB and if I am getting 128 or 256GB SSD then what kind of issue will come.

Comment: @Ramhound DavidPostill duplicate post doesn't mention OEM at anywhere. please use CTRL + F and check..

Comment: It does not matter.  My answer applies to all consumer installations of Windows 10 (all variations of Windows 10 Home, Windows 10 Home, and Windows 10 Professional).  I thought you would be thrilled to get a quality answer to your question.

Comment: I could have flagged this as a duplicate of this question: [Windows 10 Activation after clean install OEM](https://superuser.com/questions/965301/windows-10-activation-after-clean-install-oem?rq=1) or [Windows 10 activation](https://superuser.com/questions/956645/windows-10-activation?rq=1).  The question I selected I knew was the answer, because I answered it, was saving myself from writing a duplicate answer by doing so.  There are other possible duplicates, I can find those, if you want me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Digital licence does not depond on your hardidsk i believe, i have changed my currept HDD and installed windows 10 on it and is now working as it should ...that one is also digitally licenced so go ahead no issues

Comment: What I means here is If I install the windows from the fresh not lenovo OEM does it accept my OEM license. I means running OEM license in non-oem windows.

Comment: it will accept ... i downloaded and installed a fresh copy of windows 10 from microsoft and it did worked